# Visual studio asp.net markup formatting

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, format

Our coding standards have us putting each attribute within a tag on a separate line. However, when I have VS (2008) format the markup is lumps all the attributes together. Is there a way to change this behavior??

Thanks

Comment: *Each* attribute? That must produce some pretty horrible code 0.o

Comment: I agree, I want to do something similar.

Comment: I have to agree with Thorarin here, the issue is the standard and not Visual Studio...if it doesn't support it, maybe there's a reason.  This would leave your pages with gratuitous amounts of white-space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with HTML, you may be out of luck without an add-in to Visual Studio.

However, VS is capable of formatting XAML this way, as it is a popular convention for many XAML developers.

To enable this formatting for XAML go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > XAML > Formatting > Spacing and select "Position each attribute on a separate line"

Comment: Interesting...if you hand-edit a vssettings file and to change the Html formatter to a xaml formatter you might be able to hack it...not sure about that though.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any options within Visual Studio itself that would allow you to *force* your attribute to format this way. It seems that you have two options:

1) Go into Tools->Options->Text Editor->HTML and remove all the formating stuff (or as much as you need).

2) Find a coding-style plugin that allows this to be specified. I use [Microsoft StyleCop](http://blogs.msdn.com/sourceanalysis/), but it functions more as a check on already written code. Still, it allows custom rules to be written and writing one for your rule would not be difficult.